Running algorithms in package EKHAD in Maple
The EKHAD package from the book A=B contains many effective algorithms. I want to use one of them in Maple, but I have troubles with the command read.
I saved the file from this link and followed the instructions at the beggining:
#######################################################################
## EKHAD: Save this file as EKHAD. To use it, stay in the             #
## same directory, get into Maple (by typing: maple <Enter> )         #
## and then type:  read EKHAD : <Enter>                               #
## Then follow the instructions given there                           #
##                                                                    #
## Written by Doron Zeilberger, Rutgers University ,                  #
##  zeilberg@math.rutgers.edu.                                        # 
#######################################################################

After running the EKHAD file, I got:
 Last update: April 26, 2018, thanks to Daniel G. DuParc

   Previous updates:   Dec. 11, 2015 (adding procedures AZdI, 

    AZcI ); May 30, 2015 (adding procedure TerryTao )


              May 29, 2014 (adding Ekhad )

          Version of July 2003: adapted to Maple 8 and 9 

               Many thanks to Drew Sills

     In the penultimate Version of Feb 25, 1999 a suggestion

     of Frederic Chyzak was used, with considerable 

            speed-up. We thank him SO MUCH!


         The penpenultimate version, Feb. 1997,

  corrected a subtle bug discovered by Helmut Prodinger


       Previous versions benefited from comments by Paula Cohen, 

             Lyle Ramshaw, and Bob Sulanke.


        This is EKHAD, One of the Maple packages

                 accompanying the book 

                         "A=B" 

      (published by A.K. Peters, Wellesley, 1996) 

  by Marko Petkovsek, Herb Wilf, and Doron Zeilberger.


    The most current version is available on WWW at:

        http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg .

   Information about the book, and how to order it, can be found in

   http://www.central.cis.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html .

 Please report all bugs to: zeilberg@math.rutgers.edu .

        All bugs or other comments used will be acknowledged in future

                       versions.


For general help, and a list of the available functions,

 type "ezra();". For specific help type "ezra(procedure_name)" 




       NULL;

Then I opened new document in same directory as in instructions and typed read EKHAD, but I got the following error:
Error, unable to read `EKHAD`

Here's the screenshot of my situation:

Note from 23rd September 2024. As pointed out by @dharr in answer, I made a typo first (I typed read EHKAD. But after correcting the typo from EHKAD to EKHAD, the same error appears.

This seems to be a question best asked on either the Maple or EHKAD-specific forums.

You have misspelled it; you want EKHAD not EHKAD.
Edit:
It's hard to tell exactly, but likely a directory issue. Try
currentdir();

to see which directory Maple is looking in. Before a new worksheet is saved, the directory can be something like "C:/Program Files/Maple 2024". So save the worksheet with the read command in, exit Maple and then reopen the worksheet, e.g. by double-clicking on the saved worksheet. You can always use a fully qualified filename just to make sure, e.g.
read "C:/Users/dharr//Desktop/EKHAD"
(Use forward slashes on any platform.). You can also specify a path to currentdir to change the current directory. Finally, the default extension for text-based Maple is .mpl, so you could rename your file with that extension (and then specify it) just in case some assumption is being made about the extension.

Thanks for pointing that out. However, after correcting the typo the program still doesn't work (if possible, please see the edit in question).

See edit for some more suggestions.

PS. Probably better on StackOverflow

I kind of figured out what was the first problem, but now I get other errors. I should type read "EKHAD.mw". I'll ask for them on stackoverflow.
